# Chi-square test, McNemar test, or something else for comparing proportions of overlapping groups

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, percentage, mcnemar-test

**Goal:** I am trying to compare the proportion of participants who choose one of the combined options (A-B and B-A) in questions where they see A-First vs questions where they see B-First.

**Data:** I have data that looks like the following table. Each participant answers 3 questions. For each question, they have 3 choices: A, B, and either A-B or B-A. When A-First is 1 and B-first is 0, they see option A-B. When A-First is 0 and B-First is 1, they see option B-A.

```
ParticipantID  Question  A-First  B-First  Choice
1              1         1        0        A
1              2         0        1        A
1              3         0        1        B-A
2              1         1        0        B
2              2         1        0        A
2              3         0        1        B-A
3              1         0        1        B
3              2         1        0        A-B
3              3         1        0        B
```

**Considerations:** I was considering using a Chi-Squared test, but my sense is this would not be appropriate here because there is overlap in the two groups being compared. Depending on the question (1, 2, or 3), each participant is sometimes in the A-First group and sometimes in the B-First group.

Would a McNemar's test be appropriate here? Or something else? This study design differs from the other examples I've been able to find online, such as the example on the [McNemar's test Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test)

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the situation, but it sounds like you need a mixed effects (repeated measures) multinomial logistic regression model.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Is there a way that could allow me to compare the proportions between the A-First and B-First questions? My sense is that would give me info on how much A-First vs. B-First affects people's choices of the combined messages but wouldn't show me the significance of the difference in proportions between the two groups.

Comment: It sounds like you need a mixed effects multinomial logistic regression model.  I've never fit one myself.